# Return a cell reference for use in a formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have an excel workbook with paired data sets of the type `[columnA=time:columnB=data]`
There are thousands of data points.

What I'm looking to do is this: I have a table of time values on a separate sheet.  I want to find the corresponding cell in the data column of the data worksheet (column B) and return an average of the values of 5 cells before it and 40 cells after it.

By searching the questions I came up with this formula to return a cell address of the exact value I'm looking for, however I can't put it into an average formula.

```
=CELL("address",INDEX('EMG Data'!B1:B10000,MATCH(C5,'EMG Data'!A1:A10000,0),1))
```

C5 is the time value I know I want to get the data value pair for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a combination of average, offset and match instead, offset will allow you to change the number of rows/columns in the range:

```
=IFERROR(AVERAGE(OFFSET($B$1,MAX(MATCH(C5,A:A,0)-6,0),0,46)),"SOMETHING IS WRONG")
```

**MATCH**

MATCH() will find the right value in column 1 and return its position in A:A.

**OFFSET**

To OFFSET to the corresponding row compared to cell B1 you should do `MATCH()-1` (otherwise a Match in cell A1 yielding a 1 will OFFSET B1 by 1 row thus showing the value of B2!!

You want to offset B1 by 0 columns so put that as third parameter.

Moreover you want to have the 5 rows before as well so this becomes `MATCH()-6`, to avoid trying to retrieve data from rows with negative row numbers we use `MAX(MATCH()-6,0)`.

As you want the 5 cells before and the 40 cells after you want the height to be 5 + 1 + 40 = 46 cells completing the OFFSET parameters with that number for the height parameter

**AVERAGE**

Final step is to get the actual average, as the `OFFSET()` function gives back a range of cells this is seen as a normal range input for the `AVERAGE` function.

**IFERROR**

In case the value you look for is not found in column A:A than `MATCH()` will give an error which will work its way through the nested functions, Most of us would capture such event with `IFERROR()` and transform the error into something user friendly, or have an alternative function/result in that case

Comment: changed the function parameter separator into your local style (comma's instead of semicolon)

Comment: double checked my test, and you are right, apologies.  deleted comments and +1